# What's the problem in this simple \parpic code?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig, picins, picinpar

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % for the sake of presentation

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{picinpar,lipsum} 

\usepackage{mdwlist}

\begin{document}

%\parpic(width,height)(x-offset,y-offset)[Options][Position]{Picture}

\parpic[r]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{imageName}}
 it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image... it had line after line but didn't touch the image...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need `mdwlist`? It hasn't been maintained for 24 years.

Comment: alright , so what should  I do? to be honest no one ```\parpic ``` code on internet run with me. @egreg

Comment: The `mdwlist` package is completely unrelated to the issue, as far as I can see. On the other hand, if I download `picins.sty` from CTAN and try your example, I have no issue at all. But `picins.sty` is dated September 1992 and `picinpar` is July 1993. Quite old. Why not using `wrapfig`?

Comment: because we can't use ```wrapfig``` for round image just for rectangular. extra thing we can't  but image at the middle by using ```wrapfig``` so am looking for on another package. @egreg

Comment: None of wrapfig, picins, or picinpar do funny shapes. Use cutwin or shapepar or raw \parshape. Did you recently ask? For \parpic the arguments in parentheses (round) are *not* optional.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau , for shapedcutout, we still can't  do wrap around round image automatically, or by cutwin.

Comment: Yes, you do need to specify the (rough) shape. Nothing digs into the image to see where the "ink" is.